# JQuery with dynamically-created content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

the issue I'm having is that the .on(click()) event works with the paragraphs generated through the dialog box, but not when they are created through the textbox entry() method. When I inspect them the IDs are correct and in the same format as the dialog-created paragraphs, but they don't work with the click event. Clicking on the dynamically created paragraphs doesn't even fire the click event at all. What do I need to do to solve this? thanks.

HTML:

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>


    <input type="text" id="txtTask" onkeydown="entry();"/>

    <div id="taskBox" class="debugBox">



    </div>

</body>
```

JS:

```
var tasks = [];
var content = "";

$(document).ready(function (){

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    content = prompt("Enter a task", i);

    if(content != "") {

        addTask(content, "yellow");

    };
};

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
    console.log(tasks[i].Content);
};

    $( 'p' ).on( "click", function() {

    console.log("clicked");
    removeTask(this.id);

});


 });



function entry()  {
if (event.keyCode == 13) { 
    var ent = txtTask.value.toString();

    if(ent != "") {

        addTask(ent, "yellow");

    };

    console.log("input = " + txtTask.value);
    txtTask.value='';
 };
 };

function addTask(content, color) {
tasks[tasks.length] = {
    Content: content,
    Color: color,
    isActive: true
};

$('#taskBox').append('<p id="' + tasks[tasks.length - 1].Content + '">' + tasks[tasks.length - 1].Content + '</p>');
};

function removeTask(content) {
for(var i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++){

    if(tasks[i].Content === content && tasks[i].isActive === true) {

        tasks[i].isActive === false;

        $('#' + tasks[i].Content).remove();
    }

};
};
```

Comment: you must register the appropriate event to the dynamic added <p> tag.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', 'p', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    removeTask(this.id);
})
```

EDIT:

I was asked for an explanation. So, in a nutshell, the issue is that events are bound to DOM elements which are already loaded. `$(document)` selects a static parent (which may be `document` or any other parent that is not changed dynamically). The second argument `'p'` is a selector for elements which we want to be bound with function that is passed as a third argument.

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: Hey that worked, thank you. So I guess instead of putting the CSS selector in the $(), I make it the second argument in the $(document).on? Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @Zonata, Felix Kling marked this question as a duplicate. I advise you to read other answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: I apologize for posting a duplicate, I looked through a few other answers but didn't see a solution. Thanks for the solution and explanation.